# What is the 'deleted' daemon in macOS?

Tags: logs, daemons

Since installing macOS 10.12 I noticed a flood of messages from `deleted` in the logs. I haven't been able to find any information about this daemon. Could anyone enlighten me what this does?

Comment: Just a heads up, this issue was fixed in the beta release of 10.12.1 (16B2338c). `deleted` still shows up every now and then, but it doesn't consume as much as a core anymore (from 25% to around 0.4% for me).

Comment: Just had it take about 30% of CPU for minutes at a time in 10.15.7 Catalina so definitely not fixed (or they reintroduced the same bug they fixed before).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`deleted` is the process for CacheDelete, which is used to purge caches on disk. Looking in `/System/Library/CacheDelete/` you can see what services are registered as a client.

Comment: This is a good starting point, but is crucially missing a way to troubleshoot further - I hit this issue with Catalina, and all I had in this folder were macOS's own bundled components.

@vaughan 's answer below shows how to dig deeper with the Console app; I would add that similar can be achieved in commandline with `log show --predicate 'processImagePath CONTAINS "deleted"' --last 10m --info`.

Answer (score 102):

I came here due to an issue on my MacBook Pro (2018 15") running on macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

In fact, the `deleted` process was showing up in my process list and consuming around 50% CPU - more or less. After following some hints which I found here and there (deinstalling iStats, resetting SMC and so on) I realized that this process kept on being open as long as my ***About this Mac* window** was open. The `deleted` process disappears shortly after closing the *About this Mac* window.

Comment: I had the exact same issue with "About this Mac" which I had left open in the background. Closing it immediately solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks, the "System Info" window in the background was the culprit for me too!

Comment: I didn't have the 'About this Mac' open, but I opened and then closed it. Now the deleted and IDECacheDeleteAppExtension processes finally stay gone. Before that I had tried 'killall deleted IDECacheDeleteAppExtension' and 'launchctl remove com.apple.cache_delete', to no avail. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Opening and closing the "About this Mac" dialog fixed this for me too. Very strange!

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution. I thought I had deleted a Fluid Browser app (hence the deleted_helper) which was still running in the background. I couldn't understand why it kept restarting after being forced quit.

Comment: Thank you! This does solve my problem as well!

Comment: Crazy! Yeah, this open/close action of the "About this mac" worked immediately for me. Thank you for this great time and CPU cycle saver :-D

Comment: Found this answer again after having to Google this issue a second time. What a stupid bug. THANK YOU!

Comment: Thanks! I would upvote more than once if possible, saved me from this very annoying bug!

Answer (score 12):

For me, this problem was being caused by problems with iStat Menus on macOS Sierra 10.12.0. There seems to be a bug which causes issues with the deleted process. Once I uninstalled iStat Menus the problem ceased.

This issue has been resolved, see https://bjango.com/help/istatmenus5/knownissues/

[image: Console showing deleted repeatedly in logs.]

Comment: I had the same problem and tracked it to iStat Menus.

But instead of uninstalling it completing, I fixed this just be disabling iStat's "Disk" menu item and then doing a global restart of it. This totally fixed it.

I think what's happening is that iStat Menu is just asking macOS for the amount of purgable disk space every ~10 seconds and that's what's causing the extra stress.

Answer (score 6):

I found that the deleted was activated when I started the Disk Utiulity and selected disk container which has macOS system.

Comment: Confirmed this on Catalina. I have Disk Utility open constantly, so `deleted` was taking more cpu time than any other process. My workaround is to mount a read-only dmg and keep that selected instead. I also use AppPolice to limit cpu just in case.

Answer (score 4):

In `Console.app` search for `deleted` and look for an entry like this:

```
default 17:23:45.621668+0100    deleted 1426 com.apple.deleted_helper APFS Purgeable update for Calling process: iStat Menus Status on "/Volumes/ExternalSSD2TB - Data" ET: 1.452986,  results:
default 17:23:45.621690+0100    deleted     CACHE_DELETE_TOTAL_AVAILABLE : 0
default 17:23:45.621879+0100    deleted     CACHE_DELETE_ID : com.apple.cache_delete
default 17:23:45.622014+0100    deleted     CACHE_DELETE_URGENCY : 0
default 17:23:45.622149+0100    deleted     CACHE_DELETE_TOTAL_FSPURGEABLE : 0
default 17:23:45.622311+0100    deleted     CACHE_DELETE_CALLING_PROCESS : iStat Menus Status
default 17:23:45.622447+0100    deleted     CACHE_DELETE_QUERY_PATH : SLOW
default 17:23:45.622582+0100    deleted     CACHE_DELETE_NO_CACHE : 1
default 17:23:45.622718+0100    deleted     CACHE_DELETE_VOLUME : /Volumes/MBP
default 17:23:45.622838+0100    deleted     CACHE_DELETE_TOTAL_PURGEABLE : 1
default 17:23:45.622984+0100    deleted     CACHE_DELETE_ELAPSED_TIME : 0.145932097
```

The line `CACHE_DELETE_CALLING_PROCESS : iStat Menus Status` reveals that the `iStat Menus Status` process is causing the calls.

This issue started occurring for me when I activated the `Disks` option in iStat.

After removing unchecking this option, the issue still occurred, but after I killed the `iStat Menus Status` process from Activity Manager (I also killed some other ones too), the `deleted` activity went away entirely.

Looks like an iStat bug.

Answer (score 1):

On my recent M1 running Monterey I was trying to rename a directory but got a notice that it couldn't be done because 'another operation' was in process. Running Activity Monitor showed the 'delete' process running with CPU% hitting about 30%. Tried a few solutions offered here but none worked. Relaunching Finder did the job.