# What is PrivateFrameworks 'deleted' and why is it using so much CPU?

Tags: catalina, cpu, library

I noticed a process called `deleted` using quite a lot of CPU. In the image linked, it shows 10% CPU usage but fluctuates frequently hitting highs of 20% and averaging around 12%. Suspicious that it could be a remnant script from a removed installation, I sampled the process and found that there's a system library called `PrivateFrameworks` which runs `deleted`.

What does `deleted` do? What is `PrivateFrameworks` responsible for? Is it safe to remove from my Mac?

[image: activity monitor]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the 'deleted' daemon in macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254810/what-is-the-deleted-daemon-in-macos-sierra)